# Create a python distribution directly using PTVS

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, ptvs

Can I create a 'Python Distribution' with my module directly using **PTVS**(Python Tools for Visual Studio) ? I have done this before using command line but not using PTVS. If yes, how ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently no.  I think the feature you'd like to vote on is [Feature: build package](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/531).  If you've done this with py2exe or other packages in the past then you could wire this directly into PTVS with our 2.1 release.  This will give you a context menu on your project which will let you run the command from within the IDE.

To do this you'd modify your .pyproj file and add something like:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PythonCommands>$(PythonCommands);PythonRunPyLintCommand</PythonCommands>
    <PyLintWarningRegex>
    <![CDATA[^(?<filename>.+?)\((?<line>\d+),(?<column>\d+)\): warning (?<msg_id>.+?): (?<message>.+?)$]]>
    </PyLintWarningRegex>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="PythonRunPyLintCommand"
          Label="Run PyLint"
          DependsOnTargets="ResolveStartupPath"
          Returns="@(Commands)">
    <CreatePythonCommandItem Target="pylint.lint"
                             TargetType="module"
                             Arguments="&quot;--msg-template={abspath}({line},{column}): warning {msg_id}: {msg}&quot; -r n @(Compile, ' ')"
                             WorkingDirectory="$(WorkingDirectory)"
                             ExecuteIn="output"
                             RequiredPackages="pylint&gt;=1.0.0"
                             WarningRegex="$(PyLintWarningRegex)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Command" ItemName="Commands" />
    </CreatePythonCommandItem>
  </Target>
```

This example is shelling out to PyLint but you can change TargetType to executable/script/code or pip to execute different things.  And you can change ExecuteIn to console, output, or repl to have the output show up in various different locations.

Comment: Are the changes to TargetType and ExecuteIn enough to change it to a simple python project instead of pylint or do I have to change the other values too ?